# Can a iphone/ipad universal app have two different xcdatamodel files?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data

I dont want to go through the data migration with an existing iphone app. Is is possible to have the ipad version use a different xcdatamodel file than the iphone version?

I search the project files where it reference myapp.xcdatamodel and cant find where it gets hooked up.

any suggestions?

Where is the appdelegate does it set this?

i do see:

```
NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"storeLocations.sqlite"]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing magical about the persistent store coordinator or any other part of core data. They're just objects with methods and properties, like anything else.

In your app delegate you just need to specify more than one, a la:

**header**

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext2;
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel2;
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator2;
```

**implementation**

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {

  if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
    return managedObjectContext;
  }

  NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
  if (coordinator != nil) {
    managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
  }
  return managedObjectContext;
}
```

and

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext2 {

  if (managedObjectContext2 != nil) {
    return managedObjectContext2;
  }

  NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator2 = [self persistentStoreCoordinator2];
  if (coordinator2 != nil) {
    managedObjectContext2 = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [managedObjectContext2 setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator2];
  }
  return managedObjectContext2;
}
```

etc.

Comment: OK but what is unclear to me is how to tell it which version to use: iphone.xcdatamodel and ipad.xcdatamodel where in code do I define this?

Comment: In the Managed Object Model method of the app delegate. The modelPath specifies it, where it says pathForResource:@"iphone" (or whatever it's called). In your second MOM you'd have pathForResource:@"ipad" (or whatever the other one is called).

Answer (score 1):

The model gets hooked up in your App Delegate.

```
NSString *modelPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myApp" 
                                                      ofType:@"momd"];
```

I would suggest against two models, but I also have no idea how it would really work. I am guessing conditionals around the object model and persistent store.

How different is your ipad model that you would need another model but not a different app?

Comment: Its really not that different

Comment: I added 1 column used as an Identity field.  But all existing data will need to get a new ID so I have to just move the data over and then generate its ID. But I am not sure what it take to just migrate the data

Comment: I dont see the line of code you are talking about in the app delegate. I do see: NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"storeLocations.sqlite"]];

Comment: ideveloper.tv has a nice for pay tutorial on core data that goes over migration. Marcus Zarra is the guest and also has a book (slightly more mac focused, but completely relevant) and, if cost is a concern, there are some relevant bits in the core data programming guide http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW1 and http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMultiThreading.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW1

Comment: that line of code was in myAppAppDelegate.m - (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel

Comment: I have a file in my project myapp.xcdatamodel does this file name mean anything to the project or just what is defined inside? like the entities only

Comment: That file defines the model, it is used to create the momd file at runtime. you should read the section about managed object model in the programming guide I linked.

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading stuff in the core data doco about specifying which persistant store a managed objext is stored. See `NsManagedObjectContext assignObject:toPersistentStore:`. That will lead you in the right direction I think. You will probably need to instantiate multiple persistant store objects.