# Multiple xcdatamodel files in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My project(for managing students' attendance in various classes) contains 2 xkcddatamodel files, one for the semester start/end dates and the other for the course data. If you look at `AppDelegate.m`, I've set the `modelURL` to the second model. How am I supposed to create a second context for the first `xkcddatamodel`? I've tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16146289/is-it-possilbe-to-have-mutliple-core-data-model-files-to-one-single-xcode-projec). But no dice. Xcode isn't even recognising it and is asking me to replace `managedObjectContext2` with `managedObjectContext`. How do I fix this?

Dropbox link to the project:  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ivl6nw6nw8p9j1y/MDwYDaHVH_

Here's the AppDelegate.m

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  timetable app
//
//  Created by Robin Malhotra on 22/12/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Robin's code kitchen. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}

// Explicitly write Core Data accessors
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext {
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return managedObjectContext;
    }
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
    }

    return managedObjectContext;
}

- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    if (managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return managedObjectModel;
    }
    // removed some code about retain here as ARC hates that

    return managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }
    NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]
                                               stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Courses.sqlite"]];


    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"ClassesAttended" withExtension:@"momd"];
    managedObjectModel=[[NSManagedObjectModel alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

    NSError *error = nil;
    persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc]
                                  initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if(![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                 configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&error]) {
        /*Error for store creation should be handled in here*/
    }

    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
}

/* (...Existing Application Code...) */

-(NSArray *)getAllCourses
{
    NSFetchRequest *request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    NSEntityDescription *entitydesc=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Course" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entitydesc];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *fetchedCourses=[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    return fetchedCourses;
}

@end
```

and here's the AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;


@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel2;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext2;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator2;
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;

- (NSArray *)getAllCourses;

@end
```

Comment: Do you need two separate xcdatamodel files?

Comment: FYI: Links to external content are discouraged.  Please post *relevant* code in your question.

Comment: Yeah. I'll be needing 2 xcdatamodelfiles. I'll post the relevant code

Comment: Oh,and this is the other stackoverflow question I found which didn't work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170740/can-a-iphone-ipad-universal-app-have-two-different-xcdatamodel-files

Comment: Also, in the answer given here[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16146289/is-it-possilbe-to-have-mutliple-core-data-model-files-to-one-single-xcode-projec), there is a "somecondition" at the end. What can I set as this condition

Comment: It looks like what you want can be done in a single xcdatamodel file... You don't need a file per entity, a single file can represent multiple entities. In fact, if you use multiple files you end with multiple databases, which is not nice.

Comment: Okay, so I've put them in one xcdatamodel, but for the sake of the argument, how do you do this?